# Update a DataFrame based on Counter values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter

I have a corpus `data`, stored as a list of list of strings.

Based on this data I have the following variables:

```
vocab_dict = Counter()
for text in data_words:
    temp_count = Counter(text)
    vocab_dict.update(temp_count)
vocab=list(sorted(vocab_dict.keys()))
```

Now, I want to create a pandas DataFrame in which each column represents a word from `vocab` if its value in `vocab_dict` is higher than 3.

To do so, I have the following code:

```
def get_occurrence_df(data):
    vocab_words = [word for word in vocab if vocab_dict[word] > 3]
    occurrence_df = pd.DataFrame(0, index = np.arange(len(data)), columns = vocab_words)
    for i, text in enumerate(data):
        text_count = Counter(text)
        for word in text_count.keys():
            occurrence_df.loc[i, word] = text_count[word]
    return occurrence_df
```

However, running the function `get_occurrence_df()` takes very long. Is there a way to get the same df faster?

Answer (score 1):

This should work a bit faster, it's not in a functional form, but should be straightforward to refactor:

```py
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

data_words = [["abc", "def", "abc"], ["xyz", "xyz", "xyz", "def"]]

# create a list of dictionaries with counts
temp_list = [
    {k: v for k, v in Counter(words).items() if v >= 2}
    for words in data_words
]

occurrence_df = pd.DataFrame(temp_list).fillna(0)
```

Note that it's better to filter for frequent words right-away because there will be a lot of infrequent words and it's not good to clog memory with objects that will not be used downstream.